# Why have comparison operators been removed from standard library containers in C++ 20?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

I was browsing [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) and saw that `vector`'s comparison operations have been removed in C++20, and the spaceship operator (`<=>`) has been introduced. The same thing can be seen for many other standard library containers like [`set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp) and [`map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_cmp).

How do I do the comparisons in the new standard? Also, will C++20 start giving errors on older code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you continue to browse on the reference site a little, you might come to the section on [*default comparisons*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons), which simply states that:

> In brief, a class that defines `operator<=>` automatically gets compiler-generated operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`.

So, if the "spaceship" operator exists for a class, the compiler will auto-generate the remaining comparison operators using the result of the `<=>` operator.

Note that the `==` operator is *not* generated (even though it should be possible), but `std::vector` keeps an overload of `operator==`.

---

As for:

> will C++ 20 start giving errors on older codes ?

No, it will not.

When you build with a C++20 compiler, the standard library used with it should *also* be made for C++20 and thus implement the `<=>` operator, which will then be used as explained above.

However, if you use a C++20 compiler to build with an older standard library, that older standard library will still have the older comparison operators implemented.

Comment: Note that technically it is a small compatibility break. If you used to call `operator<` directly, then you'll get a compile error. Though really, you just shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @NicolBolas, can you elaborate that ?

Comment: Will I be getting an error on doing v1 < v2 ? Both are vectors

Comment: @GauravPant No, that's going to be okay no matter what version of the standard library you use.

Comment: @GauravPant if you're doing `v1 < v2` you'll be fine. If, for some obscure reason, you're explicitly doing `v1.operator<(v2)` then you'll encounter an error.