# != auto generated from == in C++20?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, comparison, c++20, comparison-operators

Is this standard behavior in C++20? I couldn't find anything about it in cppreference.

I've just tried both on Clang and on Visual Studio and it works and it doesn't give me any sort of error or warning. I also checked with the debugger to see if `operator==` was being called and it was! Does C++20 now allows for the automatic generation of `operator!=` when `operator==` is present? Does it default to a sane `!(a == b)`? If that's so, then that's awesome for C++!

Comment: It's [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Relational_operators). See the last point in the relational operators.

Comment: The usual way this question gets asked is ["Hey! Where are my standard operators!?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319928/why-is-operator-removed-in-c20-for-many-standard-library-types) (also in [this variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999163/why-have-comparison-operators-been-removed-from-standard-library-containers-in-c)).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Perhaps a dupe?

Comment: @cigien - Maybe. I'm not inclined to vote on it in either direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `!=` auto generated from `==` in C++20?

> Is this standard behavior in C++20?

Yes. `operator!=` is auto generated from `operator==` in C++20.

Furthermore, all four relational operators are generated if you define `operator<=>`, and all of the comparison operators are generated if you define `operator<=>` as defaulted.

What you want to do in most cases:

```
struct example
{
    std::string a;
    int         b;

    auto operator<=>(const example&) const = default;
};
```

Comment: All 6 operators are called relational operators, I think.

Comment: @cigien In math / English, yes. In C++, no: There are 4 relational and 2 equality operators.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. On cppreference, just above the text that says "4 relational operators...", it says "When three-way comparison (such as std::memcmp or std::string::compare) is provided, all six relational operators may be expressed through that: ". Must be a typo in one of the cases.

Comment: @cigien Both are correct in a way, but are inconsistent with each other.

Comment: Haha, ouch, that's unfortunate. Maybe I'll fix it (or at least someone should).

Comment: What if I define both `==` and `<=>`, will `!=` use `==` or `<=>`?

Comment: @JoãoPires Good question. Technically, defaulting `<=>` directly only causes `==` to be generated (besides relational operators) which causes `!=` to be generated. Thus `!=` would use the custom `==` in the case you describe.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Added example

Comment: @JoãoPires: `!=` never uses `<=>`, but defaulting the latter magically causes `==` to be generated which will be used.

Comment: It’s not the case that `operator!=` is **generated**, as can be determined by trying to write `a.operator!=(b)`.  Instead, use of `!=` *as an operator* considers `operator==` as a candidate.

Comment: There is a great article about the spaceship `operator<=>` [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/simplify-your-code-with-rocket-science-c20s-spaceship-operator/)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do in older C++ version is to use the CRTP (Curriously Recuring Template principle).

The idea is to have a template base, and the template parameter is the Derived class :

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
class Comparable {
  public:
    friend constexpr auto operator!=(const Derived &a, const Derived &b) noexcept { return !(a == b); }

    friend constexpr auto operator<=(const Derived &a, const Derived &b) noexcept { return !(b < a); }

    friend constexpr auto operator>(const Derived &a, const Derived &b) noexcept { return b < a; }

    friend constexpr auto operator>=(const Derived &a, const Derived &b) noexcept { return !(a < b); }
};
```

And so, you can use it like this :

```cpp
struct Example : Comparable<Example> {
    friend bool operator==(const Example &a, const Example &b);
    friend bool operator<(const Example &a, const Example &b);
};
```

If you declare only the `==` operator, you will have the `!=` generated automatically, and if you provide both the `<` and `==` all operators will be defined :)